# Python: How to assign a function to an Object attribute?

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, dictionary-missing

Basically this started with my problem that I had when trying to find if the index exist in a dict:

```
if collection[ key ]: # if exist
    #do this
else: # if no exist
    #do this
```

But when the index really doesn't exist it throws me a KeyError.
So, reading the Python documentation.  If the **missing**() is defined it will not throw the *KeyError*.

```
collection = {}
def collection.__missing__():
    return false
```

The above code on the terminal gives me:

```
ghelo@ghelo-Ubuntu:~/Music$ python __arrange__.py
  File "__arrange__.py", line 16
    def allArts.__missing__():
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So, how to do this correctly?
Btw, I'll be needing to use Python 2.7 on this.  And is there a difference when running on Python 3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
if key in collection:
```

or, as suggested by @sdolan, you can use the `.get` method, which returs a default (optional second parameter) if it does not exist.

```
if collection.get(key, None):
```

If you want to use `__missing__` you would apply it to a class that extends dict (in this case):

```
class collection(dict):

    def __missing__(self, key):
        print "Too bad, {key} does not exist".format(key=key)
        return None


d = collection()
d[1] = 'one'

print d[1]

if d[2]:
    print "Found it"
```

**OUTPUT**

```
one
Too bad, 2 does not exist
```

Comment: This is embarrassing, ahaha. Thank you very much! ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can check if key exists by handling the KeyError exception using try..except as follows.

```
try:
    collection[key]
    # do this
except KeyError:
    # do that
```

This coding style is known as `EAFP` which means "Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission" http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-eafp

Another way would be to use the `get` method which will by default return None if the key is not found

```
if collection.get(key) is not None:
    # do this
else:
    # do that
```

Answer (score 0):

Several answers have already showed what you should probably do in a real situation, but **missing** can also do what you've asked about.

If you want to use it, you will need to subclass dict.

```
class mydict(dict):
  def __missing__(self, key):
    return 'go fish'
```

Then you can create one with:

```
d = mydict()
```

And access it with

```
d[0]
=> 'go fish'
d[0] = 1
d[0]
=> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use if selection.has_key(keylookingfor).